# selecting a column in join table doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am not sure is the title is true. I am so sorry about that. But i think you'll understand my question.

I'm trying to select two column from my tables. I have two table and these have relationship.

First table's name is : Admins ( a few column -> username and bla bla bla)

Second table's name is: Auths (2 column -> id and name)

(they have a relationship like that -> Admins.auth - Auths.id )

And i have to select Admins.username and Auths.name.

I tried this code

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('dbBundle:Admins');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
->addSelect('a.username')
->addSelect('au.name')
->leftJoin('a.auth','au','WITH','a.username=:username')
->setParameter('username', $userName)
->getQuery();

$products = $query->getResult();
```

but its not working.

However, this code is working fine.

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('dbBundle:Admins');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
->addSelect('a.username')
->addSelect('au.name')
->leftJoin('a.auth','au')
->getQuery();

$products = $query->getResult();
```

---

Problem Solved:
First of all my main problem was wrong parameter name, i mean get the parameter like that

```
$userName = $request->query->get('username');
```

but i post it like `userName` so its wrong because there is a case sensitive.

After i solved that there were 2 rows at results but it had to be just one.

So after this point i use `innerJoin` as @157 said.

And this my final code its working...

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('dbBundle:Admins');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->addSelect('a.username')
    ->addSelect('au.name')
    ->innerJoin('a.auth','au','WITH','a.username=:username')
    ->setParameter('username', $userName)
    ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Engin,

You need to perform an [inner Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

This is how your query should be structured in SQL:

```
SELECT Admins.username, Auths.id, Auths.name
FROM Admins
INNER JOIN Auths
ON Admins.username=Auths.name
```

Based off this, this is how your php should look:

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
  if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("test", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT Admins.username, Auths.id, Auths.name FROM Admins INNER JOIN Auths ON Admins.username=Auths.name");
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Username</th>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  </tr>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The following is how you would construct the DQL query in php:

```
  Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('a.username, au.id, au.name')
    ->from('Admins a')
    ->innerJoin('a.Auths au');

 echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

The [DQL: Doctrine Query Language](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), is a great resource as well!

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

try this Engin.. You have to give correct path for Admins entity. (Application\Entity\Admins)

```
//in zf2 controller 
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

$dql = "SELECT a.username,au.name
    FROM Application\Entity\Admins a
        JOIN a.auth au
        WHERE au.username=:userName";

$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setParameter('userName', $userName);

$products = $query->getResult();
```